# Where do Aliens from the Alien franchise get bio mass?

Tags: alien-franchise

It just seems to me like these things can grow in size without injesting anything. The most outrageous example I can think of is that thing from the med pod in Prometheus (even though not the same species as the Alien alien), but they all seem to be able to do it.

Has any canonical explanation ever been given for this or is it just space magic?

Comment: If there is an answer, it's probably somewhere in here:  https://alienseries.wordpress.com/?s=Facehugger+chestburster+

Comment: *"..seems to me like these things can grow in size without injesting anything."*  You mean like a [frog](http://blogs.discovery.com/.a/6a00d8341bf67c53ef014e89d7c85a970d-800wi), a [frilled lizard](http://www.famemaster.com/uploads/product/321/4d-puzzle-reptiles-frilled-lizard-26573photo.jpg) or a [peacock](http://cdn6.bigcommerce.com/s-ukycwh/product_images/uploaded_images/peacock-2.jpg?t=1433191315)?

Comment: Maybe they are like trees, that gain mass from the air. Who knows where the energy to do that comes from though.

Comment: @sumelic I though trees pulled nutrients from the ground?

Comment: @CarlSixsmith: they get nutrients such as minerals from the ground, but carbon, which makes up much of the dry mass, from the air. (Of course, they also get water from the ground, which is a very significant part of the mass of living organisms.)

Comment: @sumelic fascinating. That's why I love this site.